# Pass a binding expression to usercontrol

Tags: wpf, binding

Not quite sure if I'm approaching this the wrong way, can't see the solution, or just reached a limitation in the wpf engine. I've got a UserControl, with a grid in, and I'm trying to set the `DisplayMemberBinding` in the grid view within the control, from the control that's calling it:

**UserControl:** (snipped for brevity)

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyAssembly.UserControls.IncludedItems">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="lstViewItems" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding AffectedFiles, FallbackValue={x:Null}}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="90">
                        <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <CheckBox Margin="5,2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.AllSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, FallbackValue=false}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="Include?" />
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Width="90">
                                    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding ShouldInclude}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn
                        x:Name="gvcDisplayPath"
                        Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ColumnHeader, FallbackValue=Path}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So in the `gvcDisplayPath` I want to be able to set DisplayMemberPath, from the calling control:

```
<Window x:localControls="clr-namespace:MyAssembly.UserControls">
    <Grid>
        ...
        <localControls:IncludedItems DataContext="{Binding FallbackValue={StaticResource vmDesignModel}}" DisplayMemberPath="Catalog" ColumnHeader="Site" />
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I did try setting in the code-behind for the control, in the ctr, and the `OnInitialised` method, based off the dependency property, but that didn't work (as the dp hadn't been set to it's value at that point).

Thanks

Comment: Tried setting it in the change handler for the dependency property? (Assuming you added DisplayMemberPath DP to your IncludedItems control

Comment: Your `gvcDisplayPath` control is a `GridViewColumn` object... there is no `DisplayMemberPath` property on a `GridViewColumn` object. Please have a think about what you want and edit your question with a clear description.

Comment: @NicholasW thanks! Knew I was missing something, I'll post up my solution in a sec

Comment: @Sheridan The DisplayMemberPath is a DP on my UserControl class, which I'm attempting to get `gvcDisplayPath` to consume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My end solution was to hook into the `PropertyChangedCallback` in the DependencyProperty registration on the user control, and update the binding from there (snipped for brevity):

```
public partial class IncludedItems : UserControl {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMemberPath", typeof(string), typeof(TargetedItemView), new UIPropertyMetadata("Item", DisplayMemberPathPropertyChanged));

    private static void DisplayMemberPathPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        IncludedItems view = sender as IncludedItems;
        if (null == view)
            return;

        view.gvcDisplayPath.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(view.DisplayMemberPath) { TargetNullValue = String.Empty, FallbackValue = String.Empty };
    }

}
```